# Different environment in (X)ubuntu terminal tabs

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

If I open the standard terminal (`gnome-terminal` I think) in xubuntu and enter `env` I get a long list of environment variables. If I open a new tab and do the same, the list is much shorter and the missing variables create problems. What is going on here?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/253